# rspec-given error `Then` is not available from within an example (e.g. an `it` block)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm using rspec-given and  keep receiving this error.

Failure/Error: Then {
       `Then` is not available from within an example (e.g. an `it` block) or from constructs that run in the scope of an example (e.g. `before`, `let`, etc). It is only available on an example group (e.g. a `describe` or `context` block).

```
describe SchoolService do
  Given(:school) { create(:school_with_applications) }
  Given(:service) { School.new(@school) }

  describe 'create_default_programs_and_year_grades!' do
    it 'checks program size' do 
      When { service.create_default_programs_and_year_grades! }
      Then { expect(school.programs.size).to eq 3 }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message says it all:

```
Then is not available from within an example (e.g. an it block) or from constructs that run in the scope of an example (e.g. before, let, etc). It is only available on an example group (e.g. a describe or context block).
```

please read the error message carefully. And you have the solution in the error message itself.

You can't use `Then` inside a `it` block, you can only use `Then` either with `describe` or `context` block.

So, to solve your problem, just use `context` instead of `it`:

```
describe SchoolService do
  Given(:school) { create(:school_with_applications) }
  Given(:service) { School.new(@school) }

  describe 'create_default_programs_and_year_grades!' do
    context 'checks program size' do 
      When { service.create_default_programs_and_year_grades! }
      Then { expect(school.programs.size).to eq 3 }
    end
  end
end
```

See more [examples here](https://github.com/jimweirich/rspec-given#example).